# Visual Studio 2019 compiler error C2397 and warning C4838: narrowing conversion diagnostic

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

In Visual Studio 2019 the following code produces the compiler **error** C2397:

```
conversion from 'T' to 'size_t' requires a narrowing conversion.
```

```cpp
struct Narrow
{
    template <typename T>
    Narrow(T t)
        : szt{ t }
    { }

    std::size_t szt[1];
};

Narrow narrow{ 3 };
```

In contrast, the code below produces the **warning**

```cpp
(level 1) C4838: "conversion from 'T' to 'size_t' requires a narrowing conversion".
```

```cpp
struct Narrow
{
    template <typename T>
    Narrow(T t)
    {
        std::size_t arr[] { t };
    }
};

Narrow narrow{ 3 };
```

I find this behavior inconsistent. I understand that there is a narrowing conversion and C++ standard requires a diagnostic message, but what is so different between these examples such that the first one is an error, whereas the second is just a warning?

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2397?view=msvc-170

Comment: `/WX` compiler option can be used to turn a second warning into an error.

Comment: @user7860670 Ok, but I used the same compilation settings and wonder why the behavior is different for almost the same code

Comment: The manual is clear as much as possible: *To make code safer, the C++ standard requires a diagnostic message when a narrowing conversion occurs in an initialization list. In Visual C++, the diagnostic is Compiler Error C2397 when using the uniform initialization syntax supported beginning in Visual Studio 2015. The compiler generates warning C4838 when using the list or aggregate initialization syntax supported by Visual Studio 2013.*

Comment: @273K Unfortunately, it's not that clear to me, because I don't know how list or aggregate initialization syntax differs from one I used in the first example.

Comment: I suggest you refer to this [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/52ca8781-2275-4b27-8fd2-4a8ca3a19db3/c4838-conversion-from-int-to-stdsizet-requires-a-narrowing-conversionwhy?forum=vcgeneral), it may help you.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT The question is not why there is a diagnostic message about narrowing conversion, but why in the first case it is an error, whereas in the second it is just a warning. The manual suggests that it depends on the initialization syntax. But it's unclear to me how the initialization in the first and the second example differs.

Comment: There are no member variables in the second structure, you just define a variable in the constructor, which will not cause an error.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT And why does it matter? They both use aggregate initialization, so why only member variables produce the error?

Comment: In the first constructor, there is a conversion from T to size_t in the initialization due to the existence of member variables, but not in the second.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT Sorry, I am not getting you. Why does it matter whether we initialize a member or non-member variable as long as the type of the array in both cases is the same and the same type of initialization is used? Btw, the aforementioned manual doesn't say a word about member variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different behavior for backward compatibilty.

`T t{v}` is an invalid code until C++11.
`T t = {v}` is a valid code until C++11 and can produce the warning about a narrowing conversation.

`T t{v}` is a valid code since C++11 and can produce an error of a narrowing conversion. It's a new behavior conforming to the standard C++11. It can't break an old code, because this a new initialization syntax.

The warning about a narrowing conversation in `T t = {v}` is kept for backward compatibilty. Otherwise it would break previously compiled successfully C++98 code if it's compiled with a C++11 compiler.

Comment: And what about this code: std::size_t arr[]{ 1 } ? It looks pretty much the same as T t{v}, but doesn't result in an error.

Comment: IDK I can't access VS now.

Comment: `std::size_t arr[]{ 1 }` The compiler can see that the value is *always* 1, which is within range for the type.

Comment: @BoP Doesn't seem to matter: even if there is a variable, still just a warning.

Comment: @mentalmushroom - The C++ standard doesn't separate warnings from errors, it just talks about "diagnostics". I'm sure your compiler also has a setting to turn warnings into errors, and vice versa. So it is up to you to choose the setting you prefer.

Comment: @mentalmushroom it's just a warning because that case is permitted by the standard. The other case is an error because it is forbidden by the standard.

Comment: @Caleth Could you elaborate on that? What is the key difference between the two cases such that the one is permitted and the other is forbidden?

Comment: @mentalmushroom For the reasons given in this answer: history. `T t = {v};` was valid in C++98, and `T t{v};` was a syntax error. When the syntax was expanded in C++11, there could be extra requirements without breaking any old code, because by definition, there was no old code to break.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, this answer reasonably explains it for a scalar type, but as I pointed above, the behavior is different for an array type. Or std::size_t arr[]{ 1 } was also valid in C++98?

Comment: @mentalmushroom no, `std::size_t arr[]{ 1 }` is invalid in C++98. This's answer applies to any type. `T` here is `std::size_t[1]`, not your `T` template parameter.

Comment: @Caleth As long as we've agreed that std::size_t arr[]{1} is invalid in C++98, we cannot justify this behavior by the fact that compiler error would break the old code, right?

Comment: @Caleth So why std::size_t sz{x} is an error, while std::size_t sz[]{x} is just a warning for some int variable x?

Comment: @mentalmushroom I think MSVC developers just made `std::size_t arr[]{ 1 }` a shortened `std::size_t arr[] = { 1 }` and it's processed by the same translator blocks, therefore it's kept with the same diagnostics. If I were them, I would do the same, reusing the old and well tested code instead of a new code.

Comment: @273K Could be. But why do you think the behavior differs if this array is initialized in the member initializer list (my first example)?